I don't understand stencil painting in texture mode
New to blender. I'm trying to "project" an image into a 3d model I have. I thought I could use stencil mapping mode. However when I try to paint, the model is not painted. The texture image is painted instead, and in random places. I have seen people using it and they can paint on their objects, but I don't know why in my case it doesn't work the same way.


The following are my settings:



Hello what does "The texture image is painted instead" means? You first need to unwrap your object, give it a black image texture, then paint with the texture you want. If it doesn't work please pack your images and share your file?

@moonboots what I mean is that when I try to paint with my pen/mouse, the texture image I'm supposed to project on the object gets modified with the strokes and not the 3d object. Like if I was painting the input image in an image editor. It even gets modified in the texture preview on the right.

you need to project another image on your character than the one you'll use to paint, is it the case here? Or please share your file

Please share your brush tool settings and if you are using a mask texture as well. Stencil should be loaded up and the brush color should be set to pure white to transfer the colors of the stencil pixels. Do you have the brush texture loaded as 'stencil' in the brush mapping in the tool, or do you have it loaded into view as reference instead?

@moonboots what I mean is that I want to paint my character's face. I have a 2d image of it. I thought I could use stencil to place my character in position and then start projecting the 2d image onto his face as I paint. But instead of that it appears I'm painting on the 2d image, not the character.

@CraigDJones I'll share my settings when I can but last time I checked, yeah, I had set brush mapping as stencil. I also tried with different colors, including white, but the behaviour was the same, it doesn't paint the character but the strokes appear in the image I'm using as texture (the character's face).

You have two different images in your brush settings - one mentioned in the image and one mentioned in the source there in the texture panel. They should be the same.

I managed to solve my issue. Turns out I had to switch the mode from Single Image to Material.


Yup, that'll do it

Stencil is a great way to add textures to your model, but there are a few caveats. You have to make sure that you have your texture for stencil projection loaded as 'Brush' in the Texture Properties panel. You need to then assign it as 'Stencil' mapping in the Texture panel of the Brush. Then, press Image Aspect to make sure any non-square images is presented as its original aspect ratio.

An alternative for some textures is to use the Clone Tool and set it to clone from texture slot. The image texture for this is added a s an image node in the node tree but doesn't need to be added into the original image. Best way to do this is to figure out if you want to use UV to map it or use Box mapping with blend turned up to get a more uniform application.


Thanks for the answer. I have checked but my settings seem to be right, I edited my question to add a couple of images. One observation I've made is that, every time I stroke it, the image form in the texture properties adds two buttons "Save" and "Discard" like if I made some changes to the texture and prompted me to save them.
